# How do I use the 'await' keyword on a function that returns a promise but contains react useEffect hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, react-hooks, promise

Currently I'm working on a project where I need to retrieve song ID's from Spotify using their API. The calling function will 'await' a function that returns a promise (list of song IDs from Spotify) and then use that data to create a new playlist.

When I call CurrentPlaylists() outside of an 'await' context and return an array of songs and not a promise, the function works as expected. Only when I attempt to return a promise and wait for it to finish executing before continuing do I find errors such as ***Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.***

I've attached my code below. Thanks in advance!

**This function calls CurrentPlaylists() and waits for it to return before proceeding.**

```
//top level function
export const MergePlaylists = async () => {
    const CurrentSongList = await CurrentPlaylists();

    console.log("Cur: " + CurrentSongList.length);
    
}
```

**This function is called and retrieves songIDs for each playlist of the current user, then returns a promise containing an array of songIDs**

```
function CurrentPlaylists() {
    const [playlistsData, setPlaylistsData] = useState(null);
    const [playlists, setPlaylists] = useState(null);

    const PIDS = [];
    const songIDs = [];

    //retrieve first 20 playlists
    useEffect(() =>  {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            const { data } = await getCurrentUserPlaylists();
            
            setPlaylists(playlists => ([
            ...playlists ? playlists : [],
            ...data.items
            ]));

            setPlaylistsData(data);
        };
        //console.log(playlistsData);
        catchErrors(fetchData());
        }, []);

        // When playlistsData updates, check if there are more playlists to fetch
        // then update the state variable
    useEffect(() => {
        if (!playlistsData) {
            return;
        }

        // Playlist endpoint only returns 20 playlists at a time, so we need to
        // make sure we get ALL playlists by fetching the next set of playlists
        const fetchMoreData = async () => {
            if (playlistsData.next) {
                //as long as there is more data to be retrieved
                const { data } = await axios.get(playlistsData.next);
                
                setPlaylists(playlists => ([
                    ...playlists ? playlists : [],
                    ...data.items
                    ]));

                setPlaylistsData(data);
            } else {
            
            if(playlists !== null) { 
                //extract playlist ID from playlist into array
                Object.entries(playlists).forEach((key, value) => {
                    const PID = key[1]["id"];

                    if (!PIDS.includes(PID)) { 
                        PIDS.push(PID);
                    }
                });
                //for each playlist, 
                for (var PID in PIDS) {
                    const id = PIDS[PID];
                    
                    //listData contains first 100 songs
                    let listData = await getPlaylistItems(id);
                    
                    //retrieve songs from specified playlist 
                    Object.entries(listData.data.items).forEach((key, value) => {
                        const songID = key[1]["track"]["id"];
                        if (!songIDs.includes(songID) && songID !== null) { songIDs.push(songID); }
                    });
                    //console.log("before while: " + i);
                    songIDs.push(listData.data.items);
                    
                    while (listData.data.next) {

                        listData = await axios.get(listData.data.next);
                        console.log("nexted");
                        
                        Object.entries(listData.data.items).forEach((key, value) => {
                            const songID = key[1]["track"]["id"];
                            if (!songIDs.includes(songID) && songID !== null) { songIDs.push(songID); }
                        })
                        songIDs.push(listData.data.items);
                        
                    }
                }
                console.log(songIDs.length);

                //return a promise containing the array of songIDs
                return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    resolve(songIDs);
                });
            }
            }
        };

        catchErrors(fetchMoreData());

        }, [playlistsData]);
};
```

Comment: I think you need a Suspense gate but I’m not sure how to apply it to your code… It’s specifically for case you want to return promise

Comment: As far as I'm aware, useEffect should only be used in a functional-component.  It does not look like you are using CurrentPlaylists as a component, rather it looks like you are using it as a service function to load information from your back end.